# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "strtod_l" referenced by "/data/app/com.example.ar_project-1/base.apk!/lib/x86/libtensorflowlite_jni.so"

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, object

## when  run on android emulator

Didn't load native library: tensorflowlite_jni I/InterpreterApi( 3183): Didn't load native library: tensorflowlite_jni_stable I/InterpreterApi( 3183): Didn't load native library: tensorflowlite_jni_gms_client E/art     ( 3183): No implementation found for void    org.tensorflow.lite.TensorFlowLite.nativeDoNothing() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_lite_TensorFlowLite_nativeDoNothing and Java_org_tensorflow_lite_TensorFlowLite_nativeDoNothing__)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183): Process: com.example.ar_project, PID: 3183
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to load native TensorFlow Lite methods. Check that the correct native libraries are present, and, if using a custom native library, have been properly loaded via System.loadLibrary():
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "strtod_l" referenced by "/data/app/com.example.ar_project-1/base.apk!/lib/x86/libtensorflowlite_jni.so"...
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorFlowLite.init(TensorFlowLite.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.<init>(NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.loadModel(TflitePlugin.java:235)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.tensorflow.lite.TensorFlowLite.nativeDoNothing() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_lite_TensorFlowLite_nativeDoNothing and Java_org_tensorflow_lite_TensorFlowLite_nativeDoNothing__)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorFlowLite.nativeDoNothing(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3183):    at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorFlowLite.init(TensorFlowLite.java:132)

Comment: I am getting a similar error on an Android 7.1.1 device. It suggests 'strtod_l' is not available on this platform. I filed an issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/flutter-tflite/issues/144